# Problem with trigger time executions

Tags: after-trigger

I have 2 triggers after insert wich call one apex class each one.

One of them call an apex class for make a query to get an Id from the first trigger execution. I need this ID to match two differents objects.

My problem comes from the execution time, when the second trigger call the apex class and the apex class make the query to get the Id, the query dont get any records.

How is this possible? both triggers are after insert, but the second one can't find the ID from the object wich was insert in the first trigger.

I watched the logs and i saw the execution order is right. So first trigger (After insert) start the execution before the second one (After insert from another object).

Its suppose the first record must be insert when the second trigger starts the execution, but like i said, the query can't get any record.

I tried to find some way to make a delay to the second trigger execution, but is not a best practice.

Any workaround?

Thank you, regards.

Edit with code.

FirstTrigger This record is always generate the first:

```
trigger FirstTrigger on CustomObject1__c (after insert) {

   FisrtTriggerHandler.FirstTriggerMethod(Trigger.new);
}
```

Now the handler start to execute.

```
public with sharing class FirstTriggerHandler {

   public static void FirstTriggerMethod(List <CustomObject1__c> data) {

      //Here comes the logic, is not relevant for this.
   }
}
```

Now the second Trigger, for the CustomObject2.

```
trigger SecondTrigger on CustomObject2__c (after insert) {

   SecondTriggerHandler.SecondTriggerMethod(Trigger.new); 
}
```

And the Handler wich i have the problem.

```
public with sharing class SecondTriggerHandler {

   public static void SecondTriggerMethod(List<CustomObject2__c> data) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter){

    //Here i want to save the ID from the Custom Object 2, I need it to match both objects

    Set<Decimal> CustomObject2ID = new Set<Decimal>();
    for (CustomObject2__c d1: data){
        CustomObject2ID.add(d1.Match_ID__c);
    }

    //Here i have to find a match with the Custom Objects 1 ID 
    //(wich is suppose already insert)

    Map<Decimal, Id> mapCusomObject1 = new Map<Decimal, Id>(); 
    List<CustomObject1__c> CObject1List = [SELECT Match_Id_Cobj1__c, Id FROM CustomObject1__c WHERE Match_Id_Cobj1__c IN :CustomObject2ID];

    for (CustomObject1__c r: CObject1List){
        mapCusomObject1.put(r.Match_Id_Cobj1__c, r.Id);
    }
    //This is the query without a match, the CustomObject1 is already insert
    //(Cause Trigger after insert was executed first) But cant find a match.
   }
}
```

I tried to made the query for all CustomObject1 Ids, but i got all the records except the last one. Seems like the last record wasnt insert, or didnt generated the Id yet.

Sometimes this code works great. But this happens one percent times, so randomly.
Thats made me think about if the problem could be the executing time.

Thank you all again.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This question will benefit from you providing additional details, and sharing the code that you have so far. As is, there isn't really enough information to know what your problem is. Generally, the more relevant details you provide, the more accurate the answers you'll get will be. You can [edit] your question to include additional information.

Comment: Thank you Derek, i edited the post with the code.

Comment: Variable naming/obfuscation issues aside, I think that the code for your first object's trigger handler is important here. The issue lies somewhere in how you're setting (or perhaps _not_ setting) `Match_Id_Cobj1__c` for your first custom object, and how `Match_ID__c` is being set for your second custom object.

Comment: Also, unless your two custom objects are in a many-to-many relationship (one record of object A can be related to multiple records of object B, *and* one record of object B can be related to multiple records of object A), your life will probably be simpler if you just use a one-to-many relationship (e.g. make a lookup field on one of your two objects).

Comment: Hey Derek, thank you again for reply. 
`Match_Id_Cobj1__c` and `Match_ID__c` are being set in another process.

Both trigger are after insert. So when i try to match them in the second handler, both objects may contain the records setted.

Comment: Here is my flow example:
- External process insert a record in CustomObject1 (with the `Match_Id_Cobj1__c`)
- Then First Trigger starts
-  Few milliseconds later (barely at same time) External process insert a record in CustomObject2 (with `Match_ID__c`)
- Then Second Trigger starts and try to match both objects by that ID.

Only second trigger handler have logic to relate both objects.